# How to add fields to a cart page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I need to add in the product table on the cart page a new field: "Sale price", and change the label of "price" to "regular price".
How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question lacks information to get any help from [so] users. Please take the [tour], and read through the [help], learn  [ask] a good question? to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions. If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [mcve] and people will be very glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Change Price to Regular price in the cart by adding the below code snippet into your active theme `functions.php` file

```
add_filter('gettext_woocommerce', 'wc_cart_price_text', 10, 3);

function wc_cart_price_text($translation, $text, $domain) {

    if (is_cart()) {
        if ('Price' === $text) {
            $translation = __('Regular price', 'woocommerce');
        }
    }
    return $translation;
}
```

If you want to add one more column to the cart table, you may need to override the cart template.

Overwrite the WooCommerce template in your theme. The documentation for this can be found at https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

The file you're looking to overwrite is `wp-content/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php`

Comment: Thanks for your response!
I want to add a new column with the regular price of a product, I added this code:  
<td class="product-price" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Regular Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
       <?php
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_regular_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                            
       ?>
      </td>
But he gives me back an error:
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WC_Cart::get_regular_price()